# splitting field involving cube root of x

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

How can we find the splitting field of $(x^2-5)(x^3-5)$. I think that spliiting field questions are generally pretty easy but only when the powers of x are even and we can factor out in square roots. I'm not sure how to split $x^3-5$ because of the cube ?

Comment: Splitting field over $\Bbb Q$, I presume?

Comment: @Watson yes sorry, thats correct

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{5}e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{3}}$ are roots for $n=0,\dots,2$